# Altering font size and/or margins in Table Of Contents without altering the other pages

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, fontsize, report

I have almost finished dissertation in LaTeX (yay!) however my table of contents goes slightly onto three pages (so only 3 sections of a chapter on the third page) is there any way of changing the font size or the margins in the table of contents ONLY so that it fits onto two pages (I do not want to change any of the other pages of my dissertation because of the way things are set out)

Many thanks, here is a sample of my preamble etc (note that I have not included all the packages that I am using in the code below)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym}
\textwidth 16.5cm
\oddsidemargin 0cm
\evensidemargin 0cm
\textheight 24cm
\topmargin -2cm
\parskip 0cm
\parindent 1cm
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Preface}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{chapter7}
\include{chapter8}
\include{appendix}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}
\include{postface}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can do `{\addtolength{\textheight}{-5cm}
\tableofcontents}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what your default font size is (usually \normalsize), then just reset it after the TOC is over.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,latexsym}
\textwidth 16.5cm
\oddsidemargin 0cm
\evensidemargin 0cm
\textheight 24cm
\topmargin -2cm
\parskip 0cm
\parindent 1cm
\usepackage{tipa}

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\include{Preface}% no file
\small
\tableofcontents
\normalsize
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\loop\stepcounter{test}
  \ifnum\value{test}<50\relax
  \chapter{Test \thetest}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tocloft` package. [Here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=de) you can find the documentation for this package.

If you include

`\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\LARGE}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\LARGE}`

you can change the font size.